# handle Multiple same ajax call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, multithreading

I have 5 text field in which I enter different kind of amount (like shipping amount, item amount etc) and on the basis of these values, I am doing some calculations using AJAX calls.
Basically, I doing same AJAX call again and again , when user type, to calculate the total amount.

So, problem is, as user is typing and on each word, AJAX call is triggering, as soon as user finishes typing, still, it is calculating amount in middle of somewhere as my AJAX call is taking some time to send response.

How can I make it consistent?

1. Stop all the old AJAX call and just make last AJAX call as soon as user enters data in last text box. ( I don't know, how to do this)
2. any other way?

Comment: try calculating the amount [ajax call] on `focusout` instead of each `keypress`

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` returns an jqXHR object, which contains an `abort()` method

So

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({url:'index.php'});
jqXHR.abort();
```

That would create the request and then immediately suspend it. Save the return from $.ajax and call abort on it when you need to.

With what you described, I would save every request to an array. When you go to make a new request, I'd loop through the array and abort any that are in there. Then use the `.always()` method to remove a request from the array after it has finished so only active requests are in the array.

---

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will
>   expose the following properties and methods:
>
> [...]
>
> getAllResponseHeaders()
>
> getResponseHeader()
>
> statusCode()
>
> **abort()**